# TensorRT/Tensorflow2.0 convert failed on __saved_model_init_op

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, tensorrt

i wish to convert my model to tensorrt optimized model for tensorflow serving, however i got the following error in , how can i Fixed this?

```
Got a dictionary containing non-Tensor value None for key __saved_model_init_op
```

Below is my saved model signatures.

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: init_1
  Method name is:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 64, -1, 3)
        name: input_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['time_distributed'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, 7695)
        name: time_distributed/Reshape_1:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I think is it the problem on signature_def['__saved_model_init_op'] which is unknown, I saved my model with below

```
K.experimental.export_saved_model(model, "{}/01".format(output_path))
```

### Update

This could be caused by tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed layer which included in my model.

This is the [tensorflow issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33094) waiting Tensorflow's update.

Comment: Can you please confirm if this issue is resolved in Tensorflow Version 2.0, as per this Github Issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33094. Thanks!